# How can I Install Perl Library of Tesseract in windows

Tags: perl, ocr, tesseract

So here im trying to install tessercat library of Perl in my windows PC, but did not found any solution to do so, now looking for the help TIA!

I have already tried this command

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Image::OCR::Tesseract"
```

in CMD to install that particular library but it's not working properly

How ever with help of above command i have installed many libraries but on this particular its not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Like i have executed that command on CMD but Its not installing This "Image::OCR::Tesseract" on Windows PC

Comment: "it's not working." is not an error description.

Comment: Can't locate Image/OCR/Tesseract.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .)

Comment: Getting this error, Which means that in my PC I don't have 
Image::OCR::Tesseract Installed, I'm only asking a way to install this library

Comment: You should be able to install it using 

    perl -MCPAN -e "install Image::OCR::Tesseract"

If it didn't work. check its output to see why it didn't work.

Comment: perl -MCPAN -e "install Image::OCR::Tesseract

Comment: Checksum C:\Dwimperl\cpan\sources\authors\id\L\LE\LEOCHARRE\Image-OCR-Tesseract-1.24.tar.gz ok
CPAN.pm:Going to build L/LE/LEOCHARRE/Image-OCR-Tesseract-1.24.tar.gz
OS unsupported
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 2.
Warning: No success on command[C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]LEOCHARRE/Image-OCR-Tesseract-1.24.tar.gz
C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Runningmaketest
Make had some problems,won't test
Runningmakeinstall
Makehadsomeproblemswon'tinstall
Could not read metadata file.Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites

Comment: Al thought I did install Image Image::Magick from the same command 

perl -MCPAN -e "Image::Magick"

and it worked fine, but now on tesseract case the command is not working

Comment: Read teh output. Maybe you'll notice: "OS unsupported"

Comment: oh, yeah saw that! Thanks!

Comment: @TamoorHassan: For future reference, if you're adding new information (like the output of the commands) then please edit your question and add it there. Useful information like that is hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Perl installed?  It's generally not on Windows...  You can test whether it's in your path like this:

```
C:\> where perl
```

If it doesn't return a path, you don't have Perl - or the system doesn't know about it.  If that's the case, try installing Strawberry Perl (http://strawberryperl.com/) and get that into your path.

Comment: I have perl already installed

C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

these are the paths